# How can I get Ruby 2.1.5 to report an object's class for a missing method error?

Tags: ruby, exception, message, method-missing

This line:

```
@page = @page.launch_profile(@profile_name)
```

is causing this error:

```
undefined method `launch_profile' for #<Object:0x007f9013d785e8> (NoMethodError)
```

If I add `puts "Page = #{@page} "{@page.class}"` immediately before the call that complains, I get

```
Page = #<OwnProfilePage:0x007f9013bf5e78> OwnProfilePage
```

What's weird is that on the command-line, the same version of Ruby (2.1.5) does this:

```
$ ruby -le 'class Dog; end; Dog.new.foo'
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `foo' for #<Dog:0x007fb64120c6d8> (NoMethodError)
```

so I know it usually works.

I've tried adding a `method_missing()` method to `Object`, but it affected nothing, so I presume someone else, somewhere else, is monkey-patching or overriding or otherwise meta-buggering things. I even patched `NoMethodError.new()` to print a stack trace to try to locate the errant code.

Further, is there a reasonably general to work out which bit of a Ruby system is doing what, when there's potentially so much voodoo and other poorly-conceived global-change nonsense going on in far flung and random gems? (In another case, 'fail' started reporting the *previous* rescued exception's message, instead of the string I supplied it with.)

Comment: "Get off your lawn"?

Comment: Removed lawn comment.

Comment: Another bit of jocularity removed in the interests of trying to find out whether Ruby can be persuaded to give usefully informative error reports on missing methods.

Comment: What is your version of ruby ? Because I'm getting the right class of my objects when raising a NoMethodError with ruby 2.2.1.  -> `undefined method 'caca' for #<Piste:0x00000006e3def0>`

Comment: I know, right? I may not like Ruby, but it's usually better than this: that's what's confusing me! 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what's going on:

It's calabash-android's `ABase` class, whose `method_missing` 'helpfully' delegates to its `world` object, which also doesn't know about my method (unsurprisingly). Unfortunately, its author failed to think about catching exceptions when his/her surprising implementation detail failed, so it's reporting not my page object but the world object and making Ruby look broken.

Had I looked at my logging's hexagibberish carefully, I'd have noticed it wasn't Ruby misreporting my page object's class, but correctly reporting a completely different object (although the object's class isn't `Object`, but `Object+Test::Unit::Assertions+half+a+million+other+mixins` which would have more rapidly clued me in that it was reporting about the wrong thing).

I've wrapped that method_missing's body in a `try/catch` that reports the real object and also mentions that nothing in `world` knows about it either.

This is one of the main reasons I dislike magic: people generally fail to provide proper diagnostics. The other main reason is because magic used to implement surprising behaviour transparently is evil.